# Dispatcher with 2 more servlet

Tags: java, servlets, dispatcher

I have a servlet named "a.java" and I want to send data from a servlet to a jsp and another servlet.

I have the following code:

```
request.setAttribute("1",result);
RequestDispatcher d1 = request.getRequestDispatcher("b.jsp");
            d1.forward(request, response);
RequestDispatcher d2 = request.getRequestDispatcher("c.java");
            d2.forward(request, response);
```

"b.jsp" is working and getting data, but when I try to get some data in "c.java" with this code

```
        List <Products> list = (List <Products>) request.getAttribute("1");
```

I get a null pointer exception, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't attempt to "send" the request to a jsp and a servlet.
Instead,
"send the request from the first servlet to the second servlet then from the second servlet to the JSP.